# Getting the github webhook payload information inside Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to access the github webhook payload information in my pipeline job through Jenkinsfile. I am able to print the payload using the below snippet:

```
properties ( [[$class: 'ParametersDefinitionProperty', parameterDefinitions: [[$class: 'StringParameterDefinition', defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'payload']]]] )
echo ("This build is built with the payload: $payload")
```

But this works only when I have defined the webhook for that specific job as below:

```
http://<jenkins url>/job/Demo_GitHubOrg/job/DemoRepo/branch/master//buildWithParameters
```

My pipeline job scans the given organization and automatically creates jobs/repo/branch.

Is there a way to write a more generic webhook that will work for all jobs in my pipeline folder instead of writing one for every job as shown above?

Comment: What information contained in the webhook do you need?

Comment: Information like commiter name, commit hash etc..

Comment: Fetch them from the local Git history

Comment: I could use an answer to this, I want my pipeline to halt and post a PR comment if the current commit status is anything but passed

Comment: I was an information like who pushed to the commit to the repository which is part of the pusher field

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to write a more generic webhook that will work for all
>   jobs in my pipeline folder instead of writing one for every job as
>   shown above?

Yes, the [Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin).